# How to use react hooks in events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have a custom hook that takes an item from my Redux store and dispatches it to another part of the of the store. The hook should fire whenever an item is dropped on an element.

Sample code:

```
const useDragged = () => {
    const draggedItem = useSelector((state) => state.draggedItem);
    const dispatch = useDispatch(); 
    dispatch(addItem(draggedItem));
}
//calling useDragged() here works

<MyComponent>
    <div ... onDrop={useDragged}> ... </div> //calling here crashes because I'm calling it from a function
</MyComponent>
```

I get that this [Violate the rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) because `onDrop` is a function call and hooks shouldn't be called inside functions - I just don't know the "right" way to implement a solution.

I also get that I could solve the specific issue by setting the value with `event.dataTransfer.setData` but I'm more interested in how I solve my general problem of hooks in event calls rather than the actual case here.

Comment: Why `useSelector` should be used in function?

Comment: @ShahrzadGh To retrieve a value from my store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use hooks inside a function. You can only use them inside the body of the functional component. You can get the variables from the state, wherever. So you need to do:

```
function ComponentExample(props){
  const draggedItem = useSelector((state) => state.draggedItem);
  const dispatch = useDispatch(); 

  const useDragged = () => {
    dispatch(addItem(draggedItem));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess it's that simple. But am I correct, that this will cause `ComponentExample` to re-render every time a new dragged item is set instead of when it's dropped? I get that it's a cardinal rule that hooks shouldn't fire conditionally, but it seems suboptimal. If I had a hundred drop-targets, I would prefer to only re-render the one that I actually dropped the element on.

Comment: Yes, this component will re-render everytime `draggedItem` changes. You can create a `draggedItems` object, and get each item by `id` or something with `const draggedItem = useSelector((state) => state.draggedItem[props.id]);` which will make the component re-render only if the specific item changes.